# Flutter: How to convert 'America/Toronto' to 'EST5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0'

Tags: flutter, dart, timezone

I'm not sure how to get it from timezone (https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) package

Comment: What does that second format mean exactly?

Comment: That's a POSIX time zone string. The more important question is WHY do you want one? They are antiquated and inferior. There are only a few valid use cases theses days. See [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) which has a whole section about this second section from the end.

Comment: @Hector any resolution on this? I'm currently facing the same issue, with one of the valid use cases mentioned in the link Matt Johnson-Pint shared.